# generating hash with range and nil as keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create hash that will look like this:

`{nil => "Cat", 0 => "Dog", 1 => "1", ... 16 => "16"}`

And this is how I do it:

```
hash = { nil => "Cat",0 => "Dog" }
(1..16).to_a.each { |e| hash[e] = e.to_s }
```

And this just looks ugly. Is there a better way to achieve this (in version 1.8.7)?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to use `nil` as key? Especially since the rest of the hash looks a lot like an array to me.

Comment: @polarblau - I'm using this hash for a select box options for model attribute, so when the user does not select anything it would remain `nil` in DB.

Comment: I am not understanding the question. Can you please clear it?. What you need as output?

Comment: @Shamithc I was looking for a method that could do this in a sexier manner :) My code looked bad, and I knew there was something for this but couldn't thought of it.

Comment: Are you using Rails' form helpers for the select? If so, you can supply either a `prompt` or `include_blank` argument to the options. Both let you specify a string as well for customization (in your example that would be "Cat"). The difference between the two is explained here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#271-Prompt-vs-Select — Given I understand your problem, this seems most sexy to me, since you're already using Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(1..16).inject({nil => "Cat", 0 => "Dog"}) { |a, i| a[i] = i.to_s; a }
```

This works in both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a case for `case`?

```
x = 2
res = case x
        when nil   then "cat"
        when 0     then "dog"
        when 1     then "1"
        when 1..16 then x.to_s*2 
      end
p res #=> "22"
```